# Ng-Route not working with Node/Express static server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an app.js that directs all requests to pages/index.html

Now Im trying to use Angular to route user requests for '/#/media', for example like this:

```
academy.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
          .when('/media', {
          templateUrl : 'media.html',
          controller  : 'mainController'
          });

        });
```

but it keeps displaying index.html.

here is the app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

var http = require('http'),

fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/pages/index.html');

});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
})
```

How do I make it not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you do need the ng-view in your template for angular takes that. I have a tip for you. Try to set the views folders like that for good practices.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

var http = require('http'),

fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname  + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); //TODO npm install ejs
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost got it to work. It works except for ' .when('/', {"... is there supposed to be an index.html in views and also in public?

Comment: You're welcome.Only in public/views!!! The node response is looked for there. If you want to change it you need to set like this. app.set('views', __dirname  + '/public');